# Service call into Controller in Test not updating field correctly

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-data-jpa, mockmvc

I try some tests on my UserController for updating the email field like this :

```
@Test
public void testUpdateUserNominal() throws Exception {

    savedUser.setEmail(EMAIL_2);
    UserDTORequest updatedUserDTORequest = modelMapper.map(savedUser, UserDTORequest.class);
    String jsonMessage = gson.toJson(updatedUserDTORequest);

    mvc.perform(put(USER_ROUTE)
            .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
            .accept(APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(jsonMessage))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn();

    assertThat(userService.findAll().size()).isEqualTo(1);
    assertThat(userService.findAll().get(0).getEmail()).isEqualTo(EMAIL_2);


}
```

Here is the code on my controller :

```
@Override
public ResponseEntity<UserDTOResponse> update(UserDTORequest userDTORequest) throws ParseException {
    Optional<User> optUser = userService.findByUri(userDTORequest.getUri());
    if(optUser.isEmpty()){
        return ResponseEntity
                .notFound()
                .build();
    }
    User user = convertToEntity(userDTORequest);
    User userUpdated = userService.save(user);
    UserDTOResponse userDTOResponse = convertToDto(userUpdated);

    return ResponseEntity
            .ok(userDTOResponse);
}
```

The response from the mockMvc is correct : the new email set is the good one.

But on the second assertThat :

```
assertThat(userService.findAll().get(0).getEmail()).isEqualTo(EMAIL_2);
```

The email is not the good one, the email is not updated.

What I do wrong ?

Thanks :)

Comment: just suggestion: maybe you should flush repository value, or  invoke the following: `User userUpdated = userService.saveAndFlush(user);`

Comment: @VasylSarzhynskyi into my controllers or my tests ?

Comment: @VasylSarzhynskyi doesnt work if I change from sav to saveAndFlush on my service